# Geometry proof using excenter & Radical axes

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Q.Let ABC be a triangle with X, Y, and Z as excenters. Prove that triangle XYZ has orthocenter I and that triangle ABC is its orthic triangle.

I am able to prove that ZBAI,XBIC and YCIA are cyclic by using excenter lemma. Then I can say that IB, IC and IA are the radical axes of (ZBAI)&(XBIC), (XBIC)&(YCIA), (ZBAI)&(YCIA) respectively.
But after this I got stuck...kindly help me

Comment: The figure [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/tvKrFQ9g) should help.

Comment: ... and not only the figure.